# Hanging during matplotlib import

Tags: python, matplotlib

Here is an issue some of you might have already encountered : I just installed matplotlib using :

```
pip install matplotlib
```

on my OS X El Capitan Version 10.11.1. It seems to me that the installation went well, and the packages are properly located in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

I get no problem when I try to import matplotlib using :

```
import matplotlib
```

Now, when I try to import matplotlib.pyplot in a python script, using :

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

the program starts hanging, and I have to interrupt it using Keyboard <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>.

Besides, when I only import matplotlib and try to run this piece of code :

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.pyplot
```

I get this message in the terminal Session :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pyplot'
```

Does anyone have a solution to fix this problem ?